# CakePHP 2.3 not compatible with PHP 5.3?

Tags: migration, php-5.4

The Migration Guide 2.0 of CakePHP says that CakePHP 2.x supports PHP Version 5.2.8 and above. My Provider skips PHP 5.3 and supports only 5.4 and 5.5. With 5.4 and 5.5 my CakePHP Project doesn't run. :-(
I thought my own code is not propper. But I found some code which is not supported by PHP 5.3 anymore:
- lib/Cake/Network/Email/MailTransport.php -> "safe_mode", Line 62
- lib/Cake/Network/CakeRequest.php -> "magic_quotes_gpc", Line 172 and 204
- lib/Cake/Test/Case/BasicsTest.php -> "safe_mode", Line 79, "magic_quotes_sybase", Line 874 and 911

It seems that my own code is proper, but the CakePHP-lib isn't. I'm not sure if these issues are my main problem, but I think they are.

Do you have same problems to run your CakePHP-App on PHP 5.4 or 5.5? What is your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the same issue but i upgraded the my cakephp version then now its working fine. 
Please see the link http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/markstory/2013/07/05/cakephp_2_3_7_2_4_0-beta_released

Comment: Thank you, I did the same. Now it works. I think in this case cakePHP doesn't support all versions they say.